# ツールバーからとび出した曲線に沿ってシャドーをつけたい

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

**やりたいこと**

画面底面に配置したツールバーの上にボタンを配置し、このボタンの上部は下記の画像のようにツールバーから飛び出しています。

このとき、ツールバーの上面からボタンの上部に沿ってなめからにシャドーをつけたいと思っています。

**問題**

ツールバーとボタンそれぞれにエレベーションを適応したら、言うまでもなく、ボタンの上部以外の部分にもシャドーが適用されてしまいます。

下記のようにキレイにシャドーをつけるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

レイヤ(FrameLayout)の順で考えて、ツールバーの下にも同じボタンを同じ位置に配置し、ツールバーと同じ量のエレベーションを適用します。ツールバーの上のボタンにはエレベーションを設定せず、ボタンを追加するLinearLayout（レイヤ順でツールバーより上）等にツールバーと同じ量のエレベーションを適用します。

もしくは、該当するシャドーを最初から画像レベルで用意して重ねてもいけます。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます！ご教示いただいた方法でやってみたところ、うまくいきました

Comment: いえいえ。うまくいったようで何よりです。